# Preciso de ajuda nesse meu código de números romanos (Linguagem C)

Tags: c, lógica

Bom, eu criei esse código como uma forma de rascunho pro projeto que eu tenho no qual ele transforma certas palavras em valores decimais, mas fiz com numerais romanos pq é mais fácil assim por enquanto, mas tem um problema, toda vez que eu faço `XL` que deveria dar o valor de `40`, é calculado como `60`, e quando eu faço `LX` que deveria dar `60` dá `-40`, provável que seja um problema de lógica, mas não tô conseguindo achar onde eu to errando nesse código, agradeço desde já.

PS: O resto funciona de boa, `IV` dá `4` certinho e `IX` dá `9` normal também, por exemplo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cot2dec(char s[100]){
    
    int i, c = 0, valor;
    char s2[100];
    
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++){
        
        if(s[i] > s[i+1]){
            
            switch(s[i]){
                case 'I':
                    valor=1;
                    break;
                case 'V':
                    valor=5;
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    valor=10;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    valor=50;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("insira um valor valido.");
                    break;
            }
            c+=valor;
        } else if(s[i] < s[i+1]){
            switch(s[i]){
                case 'I':
                    valor=1;
                    break;
                case 'V':
                    valor=5;
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    valor=10;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    valor=50;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("insira um valor valido.");
                    break;
            }
            c-=valor;
            
            } else if(s[i] == s[i+1]){
            
                switch(s[i]){
                    case 'I':
                        valor=1;
                        break;
                    case 'V':
                        valor=5;
                        break;
                    case 'X':
                        valor=10;
                        break;
                    case 'L':
                        valor=50;
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("insira um valor valido.");
                        break;
                }
                c+=valor;
        }
    }
    
    return c;
}


int main() {
    char cad[100];

    int cotinter;
    
    printf("Insira um algarismo romano: ");
    scanf("%s", &cad);
    cotinter = cot2dec(cad);
    printf("O valor decimal de %s e %d", cad, cotinter);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acho complexo, eu respondi algumas perguntas sobre: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+romano Mas não sei se alguma serve. Me parece que a lógica está desconsiderando as posições corretas que eu romano muda, mas não analisei profindamente.

Comment: sim, mas o problema me parece ser na combinação do X e do L, já que as outras combinações funcionam normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

O Problema do código está nestas linhas:

```
  if(s[i] > s[i+1])
  if(s[i] < s[i+1])
```

Você esta comparando char, e essa comparação é feita pelo valor da tabela ASCII. Por exemplo  o X vale 10 em numeral Romano, enquanto L Vale 50, no entanto ao comparar os dois X é maior que L, pois na tabela ASCII X = 88, L= 76. E você quer que X seja menor.

```
int convertValor(char s[100]){
int valS[100];
int i, j, c = 0, valor;

for(j=0; j<strlen(s); j++){
    if(s[j] == 'I'){
          valS[j] = 1;
    }else if(s[j] == 'V'){
        valS[j] = 5;
    }
    else if(s[j] == 'X'){
        valS[j] = 10;
    }
    else if(s[j] == 'L'){
        valS[j] = 50;
    }

}
valS[strlen(s)] = 0;

for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++){
    if(valS[i] > valS[i+1]){
        printf("Valor MAIOR %d\n",valS[i]);

        switch(valS[i]){

            case 1:
                valor=1;
                break;
            case 5:
                valor=5;
                break;
            case 10:
                valor=10;
                break;
            case 50:
                valor=50;
                break;
            default:
                printf("insira um valor valido.");
                break;
        }
        c+=valor;
    } else if(valS[i] < valS[i+1]){
        printf("Valor MENOR %d\n",valS[i]);
        switch(valS[i]){
            case 1:
                valor=1;
                break;
            case 5:
                valor=5;
                break;
            case 10:
                valor=10;
                break;
            case 50:
                valor=50;
                break;
            default:
                printf("insira um valor valido.");
                break;
        }
        c -=valor;

        } else if(valS[i] == valS[i+1]){

            switch(valS[i]){
                case 1:
                    valor=1;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    valor=5;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    valor=10;
                    break;
                case 50:
                    valor=50;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("insira um valor valido.");
                    break;
            }
            c+=valor;
    }
}

return c;
```

}

[https://web.fe.up.pt/~ee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Eee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm)